# The impossible task - Format string attack

Tags: c, string, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format string attack in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505995/format-string-attack-in-printf)

So guys,
This is not a homework, I was on a IT camp, the teachers gave us this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[200],s2[100];
    int a=123;
    int b=&a;
    puts("camp login:");
    scanf("%100s",&s);
    puts("somedata:");
    scanf("%50s",s2);
    printf(s2);

    if (a==31337)
        func(s);
}
```

And told us to execute func(s) without changing the code. Just compile, run, enter some data. Actually, this is done by connecting to SSH server, that automaticaly starts the program, and after the execution is finished, it disconnects the user.

Im not sure if

```
    puts("camp login:");
    scanf("%100s",&s);
```

Is really important, actually they are asking us for our system login, probably to know who has done the task. What I found out:

```
int b=&a; //Ultra-weird
scanf("%50s",s2); //Shouldn't it be "scanf("%50s",&s2);" ?
```

Well, I know Im risking some repo now, this is not a real programming question, but I hope it's interesting enough not to be deleted :)

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: `scanf("%50s",s2)` is indeed correct. `s2` is a `char[]`, which can be treated almost like a pointer.  (There are some differences, but not in this usage.)  In general, a variable of type `T[]` can be implicitly converted to `T*` for any type `T`.

Comment: Whoops, you are right, my fault :

Comment: Also, note that `int b=&a;` is of no consequence since `b` is never used.  The compiler is free to optimize this line away completely.  (This line will compile on platforms where `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(void *)`, which I'm pretty sure does not include 64-bit.  You should receive a compiler error if you try to compile this for a 64-bit architecture.)

Comment: The code is correct. Even `&s` should have been `s`. Anyway, that's not the problem. As a hint, the secure code should be `printf("%s", s2)`; perhaps you can figure out how to attack the current code.

Comment: Oh. My friend posted quite same question. Well, enough to close one of them...

Comment: You should read the comments on the other question.

Comment: Here's the relevant comment (originally posted as an answer, but deleted because it wasn't an answer to the question): *This user is trying to get an answer for one of security competitions on polish camp "ILOcamp: which is taking place right now. Jaroszewski Piotr will be disqualified for cheating. Administrator of ILOcamp, Jacek Tomasiewicz.*